# Redirect users function of role

Tags: redirection, users

I need to redirect users function of his role using external authenticate.

In my form_alter() I have:

```
$form['#validate'] = array(
  'user_login_name_validate',
  'beneficiaire_authenticate',
  'user_login_final_validate'
);
$form['#submit'][] = 'beneficiaire_user_login_dispatch';
```

My function to authenticate:

```
function beneficiaire_authenticate($form, &$form_state){
  module_load_include('inc', 'beneficiaire', 'ws');

    if('admin' == $form_state['values']['name']){
        user_login_authenticate_validate($form, $form_state);
    }else{
    $authResponse = beneficiaire_ws_authenticate($form_state['values']['name'], $form_state['values']['pass']);
        if($authResponse)   {
            user_external_login_register($form_state['values']['name'], 'beneficiaire');
            $account = user_external_load($form_state['values']['name']);
            //var_dump($account);exit();
            $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
            $account->roles[4]= 'beneficiaire';
            user_save($account);
      $_SESSION['account'] = $authResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my dispatch function where the aim is to redirect users function of their account status / type:

```
function beneficiaire_user_login_dispatch($form, &$form_state){
  if($_SESSION['account']->temporaire){
    drupal_goto('update-password');
  }else{
    drupal_goto('order');
  }
}
```

My point is, each user is always redirected to /node. How can I redirect them function of account status ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to' ? or drupal_redirect_form ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
function beneficiaire_user_login($form, &$form_state){
  if($_SESSION['account']->temporaire){
    $_GET['destination'] = 'update-password';
  }else{
    $_GET['destination'] = 'order';
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, looks very good. You also can use drupal_get_query_parameters (It returns An array containing query parameters, which can be used for url().)

Answer (score 0):

You should check a few things:

1. Use `$form_state['redirect']` instead of `drupal_goto`
2. Check other submit functions attached in `$form['#submit']` array. Probably one has redirect to /node
3. Follow Drupal [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards) :)